# What is local per flow state

Tags: networking, routes

I was reading a paper related to network security and they have mentioned something called local per flow state maintained by routers. I didn't get what this means. I googled for a while but couldn't get a decent answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

A flow is a **sequence of packets** from a source to a certain destination (it can be a unicast, multicast or broadcast destination, if the network protocol supports it) at a certain point in time. Details depend on the context, particularly on the network and transport protocol. For TCP and IP, for example, a particular packet flow is identified by the protocol (TCP), the source and destination port numbers and the source and destination IP addresses. If security is applied (e.g. IPSec), then it might make things more complicated since it may introduce e.g. tunnels, which basically create flows inside a flow.

What you mention, *per flow state on a router*, means that the router stores these data (usually for a certain time) to be able to identify packet flows. A router typically does this for e.g. connection tracking or to be able to make filtering decisions (e.g. rejecting incoming packets not belonging to a flow established by a computer on the internal network).

So for instance, when I open a new browser window and type `www.google.com` in it, this will create a new flow with the following parameters:

- transport protocol: `TCP`
- source port: the source TCP port allocated to the web browser, e.g. `12345`
- destination port: `80`
- source IP: my computer's IP address, e.g. `1.2.3.4`
- destination IP: the IP address `www.google.com` was resolved to, e.g. `173.194.44.17`

Answer (score 0):

for example a voice call consists of many consecutive packets all part of the same communication.
We call this sequence of packets a flow. More specifically:
Flow: A collection of datagrams belonging to the same end-to-end communication, e.g.
a TCP connection.

per flow state is not maintained by routers/switches they just route packets individually. they treat each packet unique though they might be going to same destination hence, no per flow state is maintained